# inserting in a singly linked list in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

How can I insert an element into a singly linked list in c, without any previous pointers.

For example: I have defined calendar and event structs. Both are linked lists.

```
calendar_1 ----> calendar_2 -----> calendar_3 ----> NULL
```

Each calendar points to another linked list called events [calendar->event]:

```
event_1 ----> event_2 ---> event_3 --- NULL
```

Supposing I want to add event_6 to the beginning of calendar_1 list of events (right before event_1), how could I code this?

I thought I could do it like this:

```
Event *event_ptr = calendar_1->event;
event_ptr->next = event_6
event_6->next = event_ptr
```

But I don't think that will work. Could you show me some way how to get this done?

Comment: In general, this requires iterating the list to find the previous record.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirements right, the following should do what you need:

```
// Put event 6 at the head of the list.
event_6->next = calendar_1->event;
// Update calendar 1 to point at the updated list.
calendar_1->event = event_6;
```